# Access radio button result in jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to access the selected radio button value in jQuery and will I be able to access ng-model value in jQuery?

HTML code:

```
<p>Selected Value: <span class="radioValue">{{ data.group1 }}</span> </p>
<md-radio-group ng-model="data.group1">
   <md-radio-button class="rad" name="radio" value="Enable" id="enable" class="md-primary">Enable</md-radio-button>
 <md-radio-button class="rad" name="radio" value="Disable" id="disable">Disable</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

```
   <button id="device" type="submit" class="button buttonBlue">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#device').click(function() {
    var makeModel = $('#data.group1').val();
    alert("make=" + makeModel);
});
```

Please advice.

Comment: why need jquery to access value ?  you can get value using angular

Comment: i need to pass it to servlet using ajax

Comment: what about $http service in angular ?

Comment: If you want to get angularjs compiled DOM from jquery you should know that the compiled result may vary and the selector may fail.

Comment: @Anik Islam Abhi no that will require lot of changes in project...i need to add a small feature so i want to use jquery..

Comment: @lilezek so it's not possible to get the radio button value?

Comment: @20prj yes it is, edit your comment with the angularjs compilation of HTML, instead of the source HTML with these custom DOM.

Comment: @ lilezek i did not understand i am new to angularjs.. can you elaborate..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the scope of the 'md-radio-group' element using the following code

```
var data = $('#radioGroup1').scope().data;
var makeModel = null;
if(data) makeModel = data.group1;
alert("make=" + makeModel);
```

Given that you updated the html template to include id for the radio group

```
<md-radio-group id='radioGroup1' ng-model="data.group1">
```